# EF Core: how to insert new record with new multiple related records at once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have added my DBContext using EF Core scaffolding command and below entities has been created in my models.
Each Product would have more than one image as "ProductImage" which is related to product with ProductId foreign key.

**Product Entity:**

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductImage = new HashSet<ProductImage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductImage Entity:**

```
public partial class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I want to insert a new Product with its new Images at once with AddRangeAsync method.

So I did it as below :

```
var newProduct = new Product
{
    CategoryId = product.CategoryId,
    // ... other columns
};

var productImages = new List<ProductImage>();

productImages.Add(new ProductImage
{
    Product = newProduct,
    // ... other columns
});
```

Then to insert all of them:

```
await _context.AddRangeAsync(product, productImages);
```

But an error raised with below message:

> The entity type 'List' was not found. Ensure that the
> entity type has been added to the model.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You'd normally do `newProduct.ProductImage = productImages;` and then only `await _context.AddAsync(newProduct);` -> you only add the parent, EF Core takes care of the rest

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It didn't work! Just product added and no one of other related records such as ProductImage doesn't insert in database.

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on in your code, can you post the full code?

Answer (score 2):

With special thanks to @CamiloTerevinto, I found the solution.

Related entities must be assigned to base entity before doing AddRange.
So it will goes as below:

```
newProduct.ProductImage = productImages;
newProduct.ProductFile = productFiles;
newProduct.ProductAttribute = productAttributes;
newProduct.ProductFeature = productFeatures;
newProduct.ProductTag = productTags;
```

Then simply:

```
await _context.AddRangeAsync(newProduct);
```

Comment: Just a little note: if you only insert *one* base entity to the context, you can use `AddAsync` instead of `AddRangeAsync`. Reading the docs from MS is also interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-3.1 - it says: "Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked"